# how to sort sequence of aws codepipeline history

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline, aws-codestar

I am new to AWS. I've created a sample Python project on AWS CodeStart and made a small change. AWS automatically deployed the change and I could see it.

On CodePipeline, shows sequence as Source->Build->Deploy. This is fine as it shows in sequence of process performed, like below [image]

But, I would like to see the same in descending order like Deploy <- Build <- Source.

May I know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible in the AWS console today (unless you find or write a Greasemonkey script).

I'm curious about the why behind this request. The layout today follows reading order. Would it be helpful if you could collapse earlier stages and/or collapse stages that aren't currently executing? There's a feedback link in the AWS console if you'd like an easy way to provide feedback and suggestions - we read and consider each submission.

Comment: No reason, I just wanted to know is it possible on AWS. Everytime I've to scroll down to see the status of the latest activity. I know that we can also see the status info from Dashboard. Thanks for the information.